# Difference between native frames of !dumpstack and k

Tags: debugging, stack-trace

I'm a developer but I've been seconded into a support role which, because of my development experience, mostly involves analysing crash dumps using windbg. I'm pretty confident doing this now but one thing I've been wondering is why there are many more native frames in the output of !dumpstack than there is in the output of the k commands. Isn't !dumpstack supposed to output the native stack interleaved with the managed stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in short, `k` walk frame pointer under x86, virtually unwind under x64, `sos!dumpstack` dump every possible code pointer (in executable page) sos can find on native stack space

Comment: So `!DumpStack` will include “dead”/“abandoned” frames as long as recent calls on the stack decrement the stack pointer without initializing data?

Comment: To make sense of things, I find I have to run `k` and then only look at entries from `!DumpStack` which whose Child-SP is `0x10` less than the Child-SP of the output from `k`. There is a lot of garbage in `!DumpStack` that must be ignored to make sense of anything ;-).

Comment: Ah, maybe `!ClrStack` is what I was looking for instead of `!DumpStack`…